# FastAPI - How to fix redirect not working from a POST to GET route

Tags: python, redirect, fastapi, httpresponse

I know there are duplicate questions similar to this, but none of them worked so far for me. When redirecting from a POST to a GET route in FastAPI using RedirectResponse. The browser is supposed to load the HTML from a FileResponse in the GET route but the HTML gets treated as plaintext and stays on the same page instead

I tried setting `headers["Content-Type"] = "text/html"` and `media_type="text/html; charset=utf-8"` i also tried setting the http status code of RedirectResponse to 301, 302, and 303 but it just returns the HTML and doesnt redirect to the route or even load the page.

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from uuid import uuid4

from fastapi import FastAPI, HTTPException, Depends, Cookie, status
from fastapi.staticfiles import StaticFiles
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse, JSONResponse, Response, RedirectResponse, HTMLResponse

from sqlalchemy.future import select
from typing import Dict
from sqlalchemy.ext.asyncio import AsyncSession, create_async_engine

from server.models import User, UserSession, Base

app = FastAPI()

app.mount("/src", StaticFiles(directory="src"), name="src")

DATABASE_URL = "mysql+aiomysql://root:@localhost:3307/streamer"
engine = create_async_engine(DATABASE_URL)

async def create_tables():
    async with engine.begin() as conn:
        await conn.run_sync(Base.metadata.create_all)

@app.on_event("startup")
async def init():
    await create_tables()

@app.on_event("shutdown")
async def shutdown():
    await engine.dispose()

async def get_db() -> AsyncSession:
    async with AsyncSession(engine) as session:
        yield session

@app.get("/")
async def home_page():
    return FileResponse("templates/index.html")
    
@app.get("/dashboard")
async def dashboard(response: Response, status_code=200, user_token: str = Cookie(None), db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db)):
    session_token = await db.execute(select(UserSession.token).where(UserSession.token == user_token))
    is_valid = session_token.first()

    if is_valid and is_valid[0] == user_token:
        print("no")
        return FileResponse("templates/dashboard.html", media_type="text/html; charset=utf-8")
    else:
        response.delete_cookie("user_token")
        
    print("hey")
    return RedirectResponse(url="/")

@app.get("/user")
async def account_page(action: str) -> FileResponse:
    match action:
        case "login":
            return FileResponse("templates/login.html")

        case "register":
            return FileResponse("templates/signup.html")

@app.post("/user")
async def account_manage(action: str, user_info: Dict[str, str] = None, db: AsyncSession = Depends(get_db)):
    if action == "register" and user_info:
        hashed_password = user_info["password"]
        user = User(username=user_info["username"], password=hashed_password, email=user_info["email"])

        try:
            content = {"message": "Successfully registered"}

            db.add(user)
            await db.commit()
            await db.refresh(user)

            token = uuid4()

            user_id = await db.execute(select(User.id).where(User.email == user_info["email"]))
            session = UserSession(created=str(datetime.now()), user_id=user_id.first()[0], token=token)

            db.add(session)
            await db.commit()
            await db.refresh(session)

            #response = JSONResponse(content=content)
            response = RedirectResponse(url="/dashboard", status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER)
            response.set_cookie(key="user_token", value=token, secure=True, httponly=True)
            return response

        except Exception as e:
            await db.rollback()
            raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail=f"Error: {e}")

    elif action == "login":
        user = await db.execute(select(User.email).where(User.email == user_info["email"]))

        if user:
            content = {"message": "Successfully logged in"}

            token = uuid4()
            user_id = await db.execute(select(User.id).where(User.email == user_info["email"]))
            
            session = UserSession(created=str(datetime.now()), user_id=user_id.first()[0], token=token)

            db.add(session)
            await db.commit()
            await db.refresh(session)

            #response = JSONResponse(content=content)
            response = RedirectResponse(url="/dashboard", status_code=status.HTTP_303_SEE_OTHER)
            response.set_cookie(key="user_token", value=token, secure=True, httponly=True)
            return response

    raise HTTPException(
        status_code=401,
        detail="Invalid credentials!"
    )
```

But it just returns a response of the HTML text, and doesn't redirect towards the GET route

Here's my js logic for handling it:

```js
function register () {
    const email = document.querySelector("#emailField");
    const username = document.querySelector("#usernameField");
    const password = document.querySelector("#passwordField");

    const userInfo = {
        username: username.value,
        email: email.value,
        password: password.value
    }

    axios.post("/user?action=register", userInfo)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('ERROR:', error)
        })
}

function login () {
    const email = document.querySelector("#emailField");
    const password = document.querySelector("#passwordField");

    const userInfo = {
        email: email.value,
        password: password.value
    }

    axios.post("/user?action=login", userInfo)
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error('ERROR:', error)
        })
}

$(document).ready(() => {
    "use strict";

    $(document).on("click", "#register-btn", (event) => {
        register();
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#login-btn", (event) => {
        login();
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#signin-btn", (event) => {
        window.location.href = "/user?action=login"
    });

    $(document).on("click", "#signup-btn", (event) => {
        window.location.href = "/user?action=register"
    });
})
```

Here is my headers for the response i got when i tried redirecting to the page in chrome:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
date: Thu, 18 Jan 2024 06:01:20 GMT
server: uvicorn
content-length: 1572
content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

```
GET /dashboard HTTP/1.1
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en
Connection: keep-alive
Cookie: user_token=7c998d32-ef7e-4b3b-bc5c-78def7d4d349
DNT: 1
Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8000/user?action=login
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-origin
Sec-GPC: 1
```

Comment: The browser will not update the client's URL based on a redirect in an XHR request. You need to handle the page change manually in your javascript `.then(response => {})` handler. This isn't something that should happen on the server side anyway.

Comment: Okay thanks, then should most redirects after a form be handled by the client side instead of the server side or is this an exception?

Comment: If you have your logic in JavaScript, then it's the client's responsibility to change the URL/redirect/reload/etc. If you're using a standard HTTP form POST (without JavaScript), the `Location` header tells the browser what to do afterwards. When you're using JavaScript, you're saying "I'll handle this myself, thank you".